# How many connection strings do i really need in my ASP.Net MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

We have an application that developed in ASP Net MVC, currently it is using only one connection string to connect to database. Today, my boss is adding Gridviews to the application, and on every Gridview created, he create also its corresponding connection string to the SQL Server database. Currently, we have 15 connection strings in our application.

So, I am asking if there is any performance comparison between using 1 or many connection strings in a single application?

Comment: 15 connection strings? Do you need 15 different connection setups? Or are they all duplicates?

Comment: I don't think there are performance issues. But it is easier to maintain a single Connection String in a single location. When there is a server/password change you don't need to go trough the entire application.

Comment: @Camilo they are all pointing to the same DB

Comment: More than anyone else your `Boss` is answerable to this question.. why there are 15 connection string in this app.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about connections not connection strings?

Comment: have it written once in the web config and access it each time its needed

Comment: He may not be aware that he's adding the connection string if he is scaffolding the grid view. I suggest you talk to him about it, only he can help you here.

Comment: `Today, my boss is adding Gridviews to the application, and on every Gridview created, he create also its corresponding connection string to Sql Database` why does that needed so..??

Comment: Wild guess: Your boss doesn't know what he is doing.

Comment: You really need only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection string is just a string which contains details on how to connect to the database, such as username, password, max connections and stuff like that. This is usually stored in the `web.config` file.

As for performance reasons, there shouldn't be any difference having lots of connection strings. However, unless you're connecting to multiple database servers or using different databases there isn't much point for this. It is best practise to reuse the connection string when possible. This makes it much easier if you migrate the database to another location as there is only one string to update. Try to keep as few as many.